# What does "%%DatabaseEx" do in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was looking at the source of [sys.sp_dbcmptlevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx) in SQL Server 2005.

In the source, there is this line I do not understand how it works.

```
EXEC %%DatabaseEx(Name = @dbname).SetCompatibility(Level = @input_cmptlevel)
```

It doesn't appear that `DatabaseEx` is a stored procedure.

```
-- does not return any result
select  *
from    sys.procedures
where   [name] like '%DatabaseEx%'
```

So my questions are

- What is `DatabaseEx` and what does it do?
- What is **%%** before `DatabaseEx`?

Comment: Google can be useless for searching stuff like "%%"... arg.  Maybe I need more practice on googling...

Comment: I still cannot find any documentation on this...

Comment: Google Code search allows symbols like %%, but it seems to have a much more limited search area. This appears to be completely undocumented on MSDN. I get the impression that the TSQL used in System Stored Procedures is not parsed exactly the same as TSQL elsewhere.

Comment: My guess is that these are calls that lock the system data dictionaries to prevent corrupting critical data dictionary rows.  Consider what would happen if in the middle of a transaction you changed compatibility level and that transaction saw the change in the middle of its logic.  How would you troubleshoot rounding errors, etc? sp_rename also uses %%ColumnEx().Setname() for renaming columns.  Note, because they update the system data dictionaries, they don't update all DMV data result sets, so YMMV in how useful these routines are.

Answer (score 7):

I think the best answer here is that it's not documented, and not supported, so don't rely on it. While it's interesting to know how SQL Server works internally, anything you do with that knowledge has the potential to break in a future hotfix, service pack or release.

Comment: You're right about that, Mike.  I just wanted to know what it does but wasn't going to use it in a production script.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting find.

System SP's also refer to %%Object, %%Relation, %%ColumnEx, %%LinkedServer, %%Owner, %%CurrentDatabase(), %%ErrorMessage, %%Module, %%DatabaseRef, %%LocalLogin, %%Alias, %%ServerConfiguration, %%IndexOrStats, %%ScalarType (etc)

My interpretation is that the %%() retrieves some kind of (COM?) object based on filter criteria, followed by a method call.

Comment: I was thinking that it was accessing an extended sproc but I am even sure about that at this point.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Note: database @dbname may not exist anymore
-- Change compatibility level
-- If invoke gets error, exception will abort this proc.
EXEC %%DatabaseEx(Name = @dbname).SetCompatibility(Level = @input_cmptlevel)
```

it looks like a way to refer to a variable database as an object and make config changes